# SSIS Not Detecting Input Service or Method from WSDL File

Tags: web-services, ssis, wsdl

I have a WSDL file saved locally (first downloaded from a developer kit, which instructs to save it locally and NOT download it from a public URL), and I'm trying to use it in a Web Service Task in SSIS. I'm pointing to the local file in the Web Service Task Editor (General tab). The HTTP Connection is pointing to a URL that has had a successful test connection in the HTTP Connection Manager.

However, the Input tab dropdown menus for selecting Service and Method are blank. I'm not getting any errors about the WSDL file itself. It looks to be well-formed and valid. I'm not sure why SSIS isn't detecting the services and methods from the WSDL document.

I tried saving a different WSDL document locally from http://graphical.weather.gov, and that worked in a different Web Service Task. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the structure of the WSDL. It was accessed with account credentials, so I don't think I can just paste it here, unfortunately. Again, though, it looks fine to me.

Any suggestions on what to try? Thanks.

**Update:** I was not pressing the "Download WSDL" button before, thinking that only applied to WSDL docs from web URLs. When clicking it, I get a message that the WSDL was successfully downloaded. Then, upon clicking the Input tab, I get this vague error message:

> Could not read the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file. The input WSDL file is not valid. The following error occurred while reading the file. There is an error in XML document (1, 2)..

I tried validating in XML Copy Editor, and it gives me this:

> Error at line 4, column 468: no declaration found for element 'wsdl:definitions'

Again, it looks fine to me, but I'm pasting the WSDL code below with the owner's info redacted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<wsdl:definitions name="Service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:error="http://www.[redacted].com/error" xmlns:co="http://www.[redacted].com/co" xmlns:srv="http://www.[redacted].com/srv" xmlns:tns="http://www.[redacted].com/tns" targetNamespace="http://www.[redacted].com/tns">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.[redacted].com/XMLSchema/1" schemaLocation="1.xsd"/>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.[redacted].com/XMLSchema/2" schemaLocation="2.xsd"/>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://www.[redacted].com/XMLSchema/3" schemaLocation="3.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="ServiceRequestMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="srv:ServiceRequest"/>
        <wsdl:part name="security" element="co:security"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ServiceResponseMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="Body" element="srv:ServiceResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="ServiceErrorMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="ServiceError" element="error:Errors"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ProcessService">
            <wsdl:input name="ServiceRequest" message="tns:ServiceRequestMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output name="ServiceResponse" message="tns:ServiceResponseMessage"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceError" message="tns:ServiceErrorMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="ServiceBinding" type="tns:ServicePortType">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="ProcessService">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://soap.[redacted].com/binding" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="ServiceRequest">
                <soap:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
                <soap:header message="tns:ServiceRequestMessage" part="security" use="literal">
                    <soap:headerfault message="tns:ServiceErrorMessage" part="ServiceError" use="literal"/>
                </soap:header>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="ServiceResponse">
                <soap:body parts="Body" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceError">
                <soap:fault name="ServiceError" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ServiceService">
        <wsdl:port name="ServicePort" binding="tns:ServiceBinding">



            <soap:address location="https://ws.[redacted].com/service"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**Update 2:** I think I've since traced the problem to the fact that one of the WSDL's referenced XSD files uses a group tag. Removing any group tags (and moving their child elements to the complexType that referenced them) at least allowed the BlueSSIS plugin to see the web service method, but trying to select it causes the BlueSSIS plugin to crash. The built-in web service tool still doesn't see any methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get any GUI solutions to work, so I eventually wrote a custom script task to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your `HTTP Connection` correctly? It has to be something like "http://server.asmx?WSDL". If not, do this and download again the `wsdl` with overwrite and then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like some configuration is missing. You can have look of this  [SSIS Web Service Task Step by Step](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BillBrannen/bidn-blog/619/ssis-web-service-task-step-by-step) article. If web service is using certificate then you need to install that to your machine.

Comment: I looked over that article and installed the certificate, but I'm still not seeing any services available in the Web Service Task Editor.

Comment: the link you send is not vallid!!